High power well pump but very low pressure
For a 2.5 HP well pump, I dug an 8 m hole and I can see the water surface starting from 2 m depth. I installed everything correctly but the pump doesn't seem to work as it should.
The motor spins but the pressure is either fluctuating, low or doesn't exist, and since it's a new well it contains a lot of sand, I though that the pump is clogged somehow and I decided disassemble it. After taking it a part everything looks clean, but I still don't know where the problem is, the check valve is preventing water from returning to the well and there are no leakage anywhere so it should work but the pressure gauge barely goes over 1 bar (atmospheric pressure) (while the motor is spinning).
I'm very confused because I usually deal with more complex systems in my daily basis and I still cannot figure out the issue.
Edited:
The pump model is DAB DP 151-251, the well depth is 8m and has a diameter of 10cm, the pipe is submerged underwater with a check valve that prevents water from returning to the well, like a diode, if I move the pipe up and down I can lift the water easily, that's what I do to fill the pump with water before starting.
The pump is in the ground and the pipe inner diameter is 27mm.

Did you confirm correct rotation direction?

I didn't check the direction because the pump is designed to suck water from hole A and push it to hole B, and since sometimes it "worked" but very low pressure, I can assume the direction is correct. Also the pump keeps turning indefinitely even with the output pipe is locked which means it has to build up pressure. I don't know if this is relevant but I have a tiny tank above the pump.

test the pump in a bucket

Have you measured the flow rate into your well? 5HP sounds like an awfully big pump for a relatively shallow well, and it might be emptying it quickly and "sucking air" much of the time.

This might be silly question, but is the pump actually full of water at the start or is there air inside? This could explain no pressure while the motor is spinning.

Dave, I'm pretty sure I started the subject by "Hello, I have a 2.5 Hp well pump", don't know what happened ^^'
Tomas, of course the pump was full of water at the beginning
Daniel, the pressure gauge is located after the pump (downstream) and it reads absolute pressure, and the water starts at 2m depth and the hose is way below at 8m

That pump sounds as if it is not self-priming- that is, when starting up the impeller is spinning in air, and the pump cannot draw enough vacuum to lift the water all the way up the pipe and start pumping water instead of air.
Sometimes the pump data sheet will specify how much lift it can generate when running dry. If the actual lift distance in the well is less than that number, then the pump will self-prime. If it is greater, then the pump housing will need to be charged or "primed" with water during startup until it begins to feed on the water down in the pipe.

Can you give the model number of the pump you are using, and some more details of the setup. For instance, is the pump submerged, or does it sit on the ground with an inlet pipe going into the well? Also, what is the diameter of the 8m hole?

There are three possible scenarios: 1) The pump is faulty. 2) the electrical power is incorrect/insufficient. 3) There is no water in the pump. Also, you could try attaching a wet vac to the output of the pump when it is running.

Regarding power. I presume this well is not in your kitchen, so how are you getting power to it. 5hp is about 16A at 240V. If you are using a long extension cord it may be too small gauge. With 50ft of line there will be appreciable voltage drop along the cord, unless you are using one rated for 30A. You can check the voltage at the pump when it is running. If there is excess voltage drop along the line there may be insufficient voltage at the pump. When motors run under voltage they draw higher amps (which also causes more voltage drop along the line) and easily overheat.

Did you check here? https://www.dabpumps.com/en/d.service/faq/post-purchase/about-a-specific-product/multistage-centrifugal-and-self-priming-pumps/dp
